# Question about intersection of two boxes in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, convex-analysis

I think the following is true, and I would like to prove it but I am having trouble and I would appreciate any comments.

Let $C = [- \varepsilon, \varepsilon] \times \cdots \times [- \varepsilon, \varepsilon]$. Let $B = I_1 \times \cdots \times I_n$ where each $I_j$ is a closed and bounded interval in $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $C \cap B = 
\emptyset$. Then there exists $i$ such that $I_i \cap [-\varepsilon, \varepsilon] = \emptyset$. I believe this is true but I wasn't sure how to go about it. Any comments are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argue by contradiction. If your desired conclusion is false, you would have $I_i \cap [-\epsilon,\epsilon] \neq \varnothing$ for all $i$ and this would give you a point in $C\cap B$.

Answer (score 1):

By contradiction: take $(x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in C \cap B$. Then $x_i \in I_i$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$ and $|x_i| \leq \epsilon$. So $I_i \cap [-\epsilon,\epsilon] \neq \varnothing$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$.